# How to check order details when placed as guest from frontend?

Tags: magento2.2, guest-checkout, order-details

How can user check the order details when the order is placed as guest. I have tried '`yourdomain.com/sales/guest/form/`' but it requires Billing Last name which is not available in case of guest checkout.

Any alternate to get the order details?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this using

Create form like 'Request Order datail for guest customer' with input box email and call function as per below.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,

) {
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
}

public function getGuestOrderCollection()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $Customeremail = $post['email'];

    $orderCollecion = $this->orderCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('*');
    $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_email',$Customeremail)
    $orderCollecion->addAttributeToFilter('customer_is_guest', ['eq'=>1]);

    $orderData = $orderCollecion->getData();

    //Get Last Ordered details from $orderData and send order details using mail to guest email

    return $orderCollecion;
}
```